# Borel-Cantelli's Lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Here is the statement of Borel-Cantelli's lemma: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20the%20Borel,decades%20of%20the%2020th%20century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20the%20Borel,decades%20of%20the%2020th%20century).

Based on the proof, my understanding is that since the sum of the probabilities is finite, the probability of the sequence of events will converge to $0$, which implies that as $n \to \infty$, $P(A_n) \to 0$. And $\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_n$ is the set of all elements in infinitely many of $A_n$. Thus, intuitively speaking, its probability is $0$ due to the fact that $A_n$ becomes more and more impossible as $n \to \infty$. Is this conceptually correct?

Comment: It's pretty much like saying "the series $\sum_n a_n$ converges since $a_n$ gets smaller and smaller". It's not the worst intuition in the world, but it misses the fact that it doesn't suffice for $a_n$ to merely get smaller... it needs to do so sufficiently quickly.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for your comment. Like what Jamie said below, it requires $P(\bigcup_{n = N}^\infty A_n) \to 0$, which means that not only each individual $A_n$ becomes more and more impossible but in fact at least one of them happening becomes more and more impossible. Is this the correct intuition?

Comment: Yes, that’s right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \def\P{{\Bbb P}}$ Your understanding is unfortunately too much of a simplification. It is perfectly possible to have $A_n$ with $\P(A_n)\to 0$ but $\P(\limsup A_n)=1$. Indeed what is sometimes called the "Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma" states that if $\sum_{n\ge 1} \P(A_n) = \infty $ **and the $A_n$ are independent** then $\P(\limsup A_n)=1$.

Thus if we have a sequence of independent events $A_n$ with $\P(A_n) = \frac1n$ then we have both $\P(A_n)\to 0$ and $\P(\limsup A_n)=1$.

To guarantee $\P(\limsup A_n)=0$ we really need $\sum_{n\ge 1} \P(A_n) < \infty$.